# Can Particle Grass derive it's color from underlying Image texture?

Tags: materials, particles

I've been following this tutorial to create a nice grass feel.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46yAuZ1GBb4&t=68s&ab_channel=KristofDedene

I found it a bit limiting though,  trying to further design the grass shapes using the hair particle attributes. Though the beautiful thing is that these particles grab the underlying texture.

I'm wondering if it's possible to have an instanced grass clump, grab the color data from which it's respective particle emerges from the underlying image texture?

Quite new to the arena of texture/shading and such, so if someone could point me to a specific tutorial that might help, or describe the process that might solve this, that would be most appreciated!

Thanks,

Dave

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your instanced particle needs the emitter object referenced in the *Texture Coordinate* node, and then check the *From Instancer* option.

This is Cycles where everything is handled by the underlying emitter's UV map.

[image]

It's doable in Eevee as well, but from what I'm experiencing right now the setup is not friendly, you'll have to use *Object Coordinates* and position it for the specific object you're making.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, that solved it. And I'm especially glad it works in Eevee.  I'm not sure I totally understand why, but when adjusting the mapping node to fit the texture for eevee rendering, the XY scale and translate values we respectively -.05?  In any case, thank you for your time, answering my question.